# Help with jQuery functions executing prematurely

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a click function:

```
jQuery("#element").click(function(e){

        var op = jQuery("#box").GetOp();
  op.flag1 = false;
        op.flag2 = true;
  executeFunction();
  jQuery("#box").reload();

 });
```

I want the functions executeFunction(); and jQuery("#box").reload(); to execute in serial order only after the previous two lines are executed.

EDIT: The functions should execute synchronously.

Other threads have suggested using callbacks, but I'm not sure how I can use it in my case.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is inherently synchronous so, if your code does not execute in serial order, maybe `executeFunction()` is calling some async behaviour, like AJAX requests or `setTimeout/setInterval` things.

A posible solution in that case is to pass a function to `executeFunction()` and call it when the async behaviour is done:

```
jQuery('#element').click(function(e){
    var op = jQuery('#box').GetOp();
    op.flag1 = false;
    op.flag2 = true;
    executeFunction(function(){
        jQuery('#box').reload();
    });
});
```

And changing `executeFunction(fn)` to call the function on async behaviour success.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, JavaScript is single thread programming. But you can simulate thread by using setTimeOut to automatically call the defined function. For your source code, it should work synchronously if you don't work any setTimeOut statement in any method.